# Finding max run length of a particular value

Tags: r

I have a vector that I want to analyze for run length. For ease of explanation, it is an unfair coin flip so....100 "H" and "T"....but way more T's than H's

I used

```
rle(sim)
```

to get run lengths.

I used

```
max(rle(sim)$length)
```

to get the maximum run length of the set. However, I only want it for a certain value, say just the H's. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
 set.seed(100)
 coins <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1000, replace = TRUE)
 rle_coins <- rle(coins)
 max(rle_coins$lengths[rle_coins$values == "H"])
```

Use tapply to get grouped max:

```
tapply(rle_coins$lengths, rle_coins$values, max)
```

Comment: >max(rle_coins$lengths[rle_coins$values == "H"])    That was what I needed.    Thanks!