# Finding index position of maximum run for a given value using rle()

Tags: r, indexing

In an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43284872/finding-max-run-length-of-a-particular-value/53265259#53265259), somebody posted the answer:

```
set.seed(100)
coins <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1000, replace = TRUE)
rle_coins <- rle(coins)
max(rle_coins$lengths[rle_coins$values == "H"])
```

I am wondering how, based on the above answer, I would discover the index position of the longest run of Heads?

Comment: be precise, what is the index position of the longest run? first index, every index, last index ?????? index of `rle-coins` or `coins`?

Comment: change `1000` to `20` and **SHOW** what you're after.

Comment: I was looking for the index from rle_coins.   So changing the 1000 to 20, it looks like the answer if 4 but the answer I'm looking for is 3, as it is the third number;   > max(rle_coins$lengths[rle_coins$values == "H"])
[1] 4
> rle_coins$lengths
 [1] 2 2 4 2 2 1 1 1 3 2
>

Comment: I found a solution but I converted the rle list to a data frame , and then did some data wrangling. Would you accept it as a solution?

Comment: Yes I think that would work

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(100)
coins <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1000, replace = TRUE)


rle_coins <- rle(coins)


##Create a data frame with information
##Index start refers to the index where the run starts
k <- tibble(value = rle_coins$values,
       streak = rle_coins$lengths) %>%
  mutate(index_start = c(1, rep(0,length(rle_coins$lengths)-1)))

#For loop to mutate the index_start variable
for(i in 2:nrow(k)){
    k$index_start[i] <- k$index_start[i-1] + k$streak[i-1]
}
remove(i)

##Filtering the data frame to obtain the largest run
k %>% group_by(value) %>% top_n(1,streak) %>% filter(value == "H")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep("H", rle_coins$values)[which.max(rle_coins$lengths[rle_coins$values=="H"])]
```

Comment: Please add some description to your code.